# C# SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, savefiledialog

I am using the savefiledialog to save a file. Now I need to check if the name already exists.

If it exists the user needs to get a chance to change the name or overwrite the already existing file.

I have tried it with everything and searched a lot but can't find a solution while I technically think it should be easy to do. In the if (`File.Exists(Convert.ToString(infor)) == true`) the check must take place.

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = ".xlsx Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(sfd.FileName);
    string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sfd.FileName);

    for (int i = 0; i < toSave.Count; i++)
    {
        FileInfo infor = new FileInfo(path + @"\" + filename + "_" + exportlist[i].name + ".xlsx");
        if (File.Exists(Convert.ToString(infor)) == true)
        {

        }
        toSave[i].SaveAs(infor);
        MessageBox.Show("Succesvol opgeslagen als: " + infor);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the if statement,  why not just: if(infor.Exists)... ? I know that isn't answering your question, just an observation about the code...

Comment: Also `== true` is redundant.

Answer (score 6):

Just use the `OverwritePrompt` property of `SaveFileDialog`:

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog{ Filter = ".xlsx Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx",
                                         OverwritePrompt = true };
```

MSDN link on `OverwritePrompt` can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.overwriteprompt(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the overwrite but now the user doesn't get the chance to choose between filling in another name or overwrite

Comment: Clicking "No" on the overwrite prompt should just go back to the dialog to try again.

Comment: see the answer of @roryap below to be aware of a race condition that might still produce the situation that the user selected a non-existing file but when your code tries to write, the file exists in the meantime.

Answer (score 4):

do this instead

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = ".xlsx Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
sfd.OverwritePrompt = true;
```

That should do the work for you

Comment: I made this from it but I don't get a message that the file will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an approach like this:

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = ".xlsx Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";

do
{
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(sfd.FileName);
        string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sfd.FileName);

        try
        {
            toSave[i].SaveAs(infor);
            break;
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException)
        {
            //inform user file exists or that there was another issue saving to that file name and that they'll need to pick another one.
        }
    }
} while (true);

MessageBox.Show("Succesvol opgeslagen als: " + infor);
```

Catching an exception instead of using `File.Exists` is really the only way to do it, because something external could create the file between `File.Exists` and actually writing it, thus throwing an exception you'd have to handle anyway.

This code will loop and continue to prompt the user until the file is successfully written.

Comment: Good point mentioning the race condition between File.Exists and the very moment you actually try to write the file. There really is no other way to solve this but to try to open the file. This is not even by design, but by algorithm theory :)