# Saving an Image of Chart With a SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, charts, savefiledialog

On button click, my program captures a screenshot of a chart, titled chartMain. Code below:

```
private void buttonScreenshot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.chartMain.SaveImage("C:/capture.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
}
```

However, this doesn't allow the user to specify the save location so I was wondering how I would implement SaveFileDialog to allow the user to choose where to save it.

Could someone please point me in the right direction as I am currently stuck.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Say I implement a SaveFileDialog feature. Once the location has been specified and the user clicks OK, then it takes a screenshot of the chart, what do I use for the otherwise hardcoded file path? This is what I'm stuck with.

Comment: See answers below, the bit you need is the `FileName` property of the dialog.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# SaveFileDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197046/c-sharp-savefiledialog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple example, modify to your needs (I would check out [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653573.aspx) page though):

```
var save = new SaveFileDialog();
save.Filter = "PNG files (*.png)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
if(save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    this.chartMain.SaveImage(save.FileName, ChartImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much and I shall.

Comment: @CuriousLekgolo Cool, no probs

Answer (score 2):

This should take care of it for you:

```
SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   this.chartMain.SaveImage(dialog.FileName, ChartImageFormat.Png);
}
```